# Direction of gradient from level surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In the diagram below, we see a level surface with a gradient.

As a consequence of the multivariable chain rule, the gradient is normal to the surface. That's clear to me.

Why is the gradient pointing outward rather than into the sphere?

I understand that if it were, it would be a negative gradient, but that's a consequence, not an explanation.

Why does the gradient have to point away from a level set rather than into it?

[image: Level surface with gradient]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient points towards the direction in which function value is increasing (in maximum sense). I guess the value of the function is increasing as you move away from the origin as I can see from the level curves. Hence it is pointing away from the origin.

Elaboration:

Say you are in mountain, then all rings at constant heights are level curves. Now the gradient is the direction in which if you move the value of the function (the height) will increase, also if you take the negative gradient direction, you will start descending. Question is why it happens.

The answer lies in how slope is defined. Take one variable case, say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $, if this is positive then going along the direction of the slope (i.e. increasing $x$) will increase the value of my function. If the slope is negative, the function value will start increasing as we move along the slope (in -ive $x$ direction, remember the slope is negative) . The similar analogy applies to multivariable case.

Please refer a good text (may be Thomas), first learn how slope is defined in arbitrary direction, and then see how it applies in gradient case (using dot product).

Comment: The function in question is $ \ f(x,y,z) \ = \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ $ , for which the "level curves" are concentric spherical surfaces.  The function is increasing in the direction of increasing radii.  @Marty B. Understand that the choice of "outward" gradient is a convention, to avoid ambiguity in describing it.  One can always choose an "inward-pointing" normal vector by simply declaring $ \ \vec{n} \ = \ -\nabla f \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner By inverting the sign you are no longer pointing towards the maximum direction but towards the minimum direction.

Comment: Exactly.  I am not disagreeing with anything you said -- the convention of the definition of gradient is to point in the direction of most rapid increase of the function.  It is "normal vector" that is ambiguous (as one may give it any non-zero length), and even "unit normal vector" can point in either the "maximal increase" or "maximal decrease" direction.  _Gradient_ is defined as you have described.

Comment: @user3001408 Why does moving away from a level surface or level curve imply an increase in the function?

Comment: @user3001408 Perhaps it sounded like I was saying otherwise in my first remark.  What I meant is that, historically, we could have just as easily chosen to define "gradient" as pointing in the direction of most rapid decrease (in fact, there are applications where negative gradient is of interest).  But the _convention_ chosen is to use the direction of greatest increase.

Comment: I still don't see why moving away from a level surface or level curve imply an increase in the function. Let's say I'm on a mountain. I look at a topological map. These rings on the map are, in fact, level curves. I find which curve I'm on. If I move away from that level curve (outward), I go DOWN the mountain, the function decreases. So I don't see why moving away from the level set implies an increase in the function. Can someone explain?

Comment: Adding something to my original answer!

Comment: OK. I think I get it now. A positive gradient is analogous to a positive slope. Moving away from a level set is analogous to moving away from a point. Moving away from a level set (or outward from a level surface) in the direction of positive gradient is analogous to moving away from a point in the direction of positive slope. Moving away from a level set in the direction of negative gradient (or inward from a level surface) is analogous to moving away from a point in the direction of negative slope.

Comment: @colormegone and user3001408: I think that by discussing the negative gradient as a normal, the alternative definition of gradient and the increase of a function in the direction of the gradient, you're not really addressing the original question: why does the gradient, as we know it, point in this particular direction that we call outwards? As colormegone said, this is about the meaning of "outwards". And I say that it's also about a choice of function

Comment: @MartyB. A positive gradient is like a positive slope, or more precisely, gives the direction of highest slope. But you have to be careful about the idea of "moving away from a level set". The direction is important, as well as the function that defines the gradient and, as colormegone said, the meaning of "outwards". Check my answer for examples

Answer (score 1):

That's not always true.

In general, the gradient points towards arguments in which function value is higher. Therefore, a gradient pointing "outwards" indicates that we need to move outwards to find higher function values, but sometimes we find higher function values by moving inwards. This depends on what "outwards" means, because we usually get it from context and don't define it rigorously. And it also depends on which function we use to define the gradient, because we don't get a gradient from a surface alone.

Consider the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$. This is a level set of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, and in this case the gradient of $f$ points "outwards" because we took $f$ such that higher values of $f(x,y,z)$ correspond to spheres with higher radii. But we could also consider this sphere as a level set of $g(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1}$ or $h(x,y,z)=-(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ and in this case the gradient points inwards, because higher values of $g(x,y,z)$ correspond to spheres with smaller radii.

Similarly, the level curves of the mountain $f(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$ are circumferences and for this $f$ the gradient points inwards. But for $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ (the valley) or $h(x,y)=(-x^2-y^2)^{-1}$ the gradient points outwards.

Of course, we could get a different surface normal by taking the opposite of one of these gradients or by redefining the gradient in such a way that it points in the direction of decrease, but that's not the question here. We're assuming the usual definition of gradient, that is coherent with the way derivatives are defined in the one variable case.